# Airflow scheduler failure notification via slack

Tags: airflow, etl, slack, airflow-scheduler

I am a newbie to airflow so pardon me for any stupid assumptions I make about it, I have ETL set up at my work where I am running Airflow on company cluster and have a dag with few tasks in it. It is a possible scenario that the cluster on which airflow runs crashes , in that event the DAG will not run.

I wanted to check if we can set up notification on failure of airflow scheduler , my online reading has thrown up several useful articles to monitor the DAG itself , but if the scheduler fails then these failure notifications won't be triggered (correct me if thats not how it works)

Open the below link in incognito if you face firewall and don't have subscription

https://medium.com/datareply/integrating-slack-alerts-in-airflow-c9dcd155105

Comment: Did you try using webhooks as written in the article ?

Comment: I have already raised request with my slack admins for creating apps , my question is that if scheduler fails the , would this webhook link up catch that ?

Comment: This depends on AirFlow failure handling module. As for slack webhooks, anything posted correctly there will end up in configured channel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an external software for this, like Datadog.

Here you can find more information:
https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/airflow/?tab=host

Basically, you have to connect externally Datadog to Airflow through statsD.

In my case, I have Airflow deployed through docker-compose, and Datadog is another container (from Datadog official Docker image), linked to the scheduler and webserver containers.

You can also use Grafana and Prometeus (also through statsD), which is the Open Source way https://databand.ai/blog/everyday-data-engineering-monitoring-airflow-with-prometheus-statsd-and-grafana/

Comment: Hey Javier ,
would it allow me to catch airflow scheduler crashes , or scheduler crash and dag crash are the same ?

Comment: It allows you to catch scheduler crashes. We have an alarm for precisely that case. It sends us an Slack/email when the scheduler is down for more than 15 minutes

Comment: Hey I just checked and the Datadog app is present in slack apps too, though it mentioned as deprecated , is there a newer version out there you are using ?

Comment: I have updated the answer for adding mor info